# Load javascript via php so that it isn't directly visible in the source?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is it possible to make a webpage load some javascript via php so that it's not visible in the source?

Currently my php files look similar to below, I want to be able to be able to load as much as possible via php so that it's not visible in the source... **(it's fine if they can see it all in inspect element)** how can this be done?

```
<?php 
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.75">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!-- @import url("style.css");
        -->
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>'
;?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? It sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Please don't write out all your script like that

Comment: You can't do it in `PHP`. You can use `javascript` to add more `script files`

Comment: Your best bet is to uglify the javascript so that a human have hard time to understand whats going on in it.

Comment: You could load JavaScript after the page is loaded by using ajax, but since it's client side the user always has access to it. Use minify instead to obfuscate your code. Also, you shouldn't echo your page like that, just have HTML code written in a normal way and then echo dynamic content from PHP.

Comment: Not possible but you can use some JS scrambler like [this](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/) or Google "javascript scrambler ;)

Comment: @bvx89 that sounds like what I was trying to acheive with the ajax loading of the js, could you give an example and how do you mean by echo the dynamic content from php?

Comment: In your header you could load your title dynamically depending on which site you're on, so it would look like:
<head>
<title>MySite - <?php echo $page; ?></title>
</head>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I think as everyone suggested, it almost cannot be done!

However, if your code is sensetive in any manner, try using obfuscators so that the code will not be readable by human eye.

Here are few obfuscation services:

1. [Free Javascript Obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)
2. [Uglify JS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs)

Answer (score 6):

It can't be done. JavaScript is client side. If a user wants to see it, they'll see it. It will be available when they view the source.

If you want to try to make your JavaScript code a little more obscure, I'd suggest minifying it. Makes it a little harder to read.